# StructureMap: How do you define a default constructor for an open generic?

Tags: structuremap

I have some configuration with open generics that looks like this:

```
  x.ForRequestedType(typeof(IRepository<>))
      .TheDefaultIsConcreteType(typeof(MyRepository<>));
```

I need to tell SM that it should NOT use the greediest constructor when building my repo. How do I do this?

Its easy enough when I'm using ForRequestedType<>, but it appears I can't do it with the non-generic version.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late reply, but you could try placing the `[DefaultConstructor]` attribute on the constructor you wish for default.